# prioritize positive over negative value in min python function.

Tags: python, distance, min

Say i have a list of values:

```
l = [1, -1]
```

and i want to take the list value that is closer to other value, for example 0,
i can go with this:

```
min(l, key=lambda v: abs(v - 0))
# prints 1
```

but if i change the order of the values in the list like:

```
l = [-1, 1]
```

and i call the same function above i get `-1` instead of `1`, so how can i always get
the positive value where there are both positive and negative values at the same distance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have the lambda function return a tuple, the second item of which indicates whether it is positive or negative:

```
min(l, key=lambda v: (abs(v - 0), v < 0))
```

When comparing tuples, the first item is prioritized, followed by the second. Thus, the second item serves as a "tiebreaker". Since `False < True`, this would prioritize `1` (which becomes `(1, False)`) to `-1` (which becomes `(1, True)`.